# It it okay to edit definitions in GCC "bits/g++config.h"?

Tags: c++, gcc

Specifically, I want to set `_GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING` to `0` so the std::string move-constructor is declared `noexcept` by the library.

I changed it and my code compiles fine, however I did not find any documentation about this file anywhere. I have a bad feeling about changing internal parts of the library.

On the other hand, this file *seems* like it is allowed to be edited.

Is this safe to do?

Comment: Depends on whether you understand what it does and whether the compiler knows you've made the changes.  Generally, it is an extremely bad idea to make such changes unless it is documented somewhere that you can.  The header probably documents how G++ behaves; you changing the value may not change the compiler, but may misinform your code and lead to obscure problems.  Treat the headers in `/usr/include` and the compiler's internal header directory as sacrosanct.  Assume you will be struck by lightning if you tamper with them.

Comment: _"Is this safe to do?"_ No, it isn't, that's a very bad idea! Try to use a compiler option like `-D_GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING=0` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change system include files. Your package manager will hate you.

Comment: Fully agreed. And worse, some of the programs you work with may stop working, because they were expecting genuine g++. And you may have troubles linking with libraries compiled without this modification...